# Is it possible to store data on specific images on OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, memory, image-processing, computer-vision

I just wanted to know if this possible. For example, if I was to find contours in a specific image (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html), could I store the data that represents the contours in the specific image? Then could I have another image and detect the contours and store them and then compare the contour data of each image to each other to see if there are objects with related geometric features?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, so I apologize for my poor answer in advance. Anyway, let me try to answer them:

> 1. could I store the data that represents the contours in the specific image?

If you [take a look at those docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), you might notice that `findContours()` uses one argument as input, and another as output, so you can't pass the input `image` to this method and also used it to store the output `contours` because the method will throw an exception (I've tried this in the past).

> 2. could I have another image and detect the contours and store them and then compare the contour data of each image to each other to see if there are objects with related geometric features?

It is possible to analyse 2 contours and compare them to each other. In fact, section [**3. Match Shapes** of this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#match-shapes) shares Python code that uses *hu-moments* to demonstrate how this can be achieved (invariant to translation, rotation and scale):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('star.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('star2.jpg',0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img1, 127, 255,0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img2, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt1 = contours[0]
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2,2,1)
cnt2 = contours[0]

ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1,cnt2,1,0.0)
print ret
```